# Why is the default CSS styling different across browsers?

Tags: css, browser

Most CSS frameworks nowadays use either [Reset CSS](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to make sure that all elements have the same initial style across different browsers.

My question is - why? Is there a reason why every browser (or rather, rendering engine) has slightly different default styles? Also, is there any good reason why this is not standardized yet, to remove the need for "resetting" it since most people will want to reset it anyway?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculating reasons to some phenomena, not about practical programming problems.

Answer (score -1):

It is always better Reset the  style.

The reason that different browsers had different standard value is because they are from different point of view projekted.

Historically, different browser providers have implemented HTML standards
differently, leading to significant differences between the presentation of websites on
different browsers.

Today, the major browsers generally adhere to a high
level of standards
compliance (for HTML4) and very few users still use the problematic Internet Explorer 6
browser, so this is somewhat less of a worry than it used to be.

source:  [Hier](http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/PRDV251-OC-1.1.6BrowserCompatibility-FINAL.pdf)

There are many people that use old browser, and we programmer must code so all get the better result of our work.